# SMTP connection read welcome message

Tags: go, smtp

I try to connect on smtp server and read welcome message. This is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "time"
    "net/smtp"
    "bufio"
)

func main() {
    // attempt a connection
    conn, _ := net.DialTimeout("tcp", "88.198.24.108:25", 15 * time.Second)

    buf := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    bytes, _ := buf.ReadBytes('\n')
    fmt.Printf("%s", bytes)


    client, err := smtp.NewClient(conn, "88.198.24.108")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("1>>", err)
        return
    }

    client.Quit()
    conn.Close()
}
```

Problem is after read welcome message stop running and wait to go in timeout, I want to read/print welcome message and continue.

```
220 example.me ESMTP Haraka/2.8.18 ready
1>> 421 timeout
```

Comment: You have already read the welcome message. Why are you doing this? Do you intend to send mail, or do something else?

Comment: @MichaelHampton  i need to check if server is Haraka or something else

Comment: Then why do you call `smtp.NewClient()`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton if the server is diferent to `Haraka`, in this case i send email.

Answer (score 1):

An inspection of the standard library source indicates that `smtp.NewClient()` reads the SMTP banner from the remote host and throws it away.

```
func NewClient(conn net.Conn, host string) (*Client, error) {
    text := textproto.NewConn(conn)
    _, _, err := text.ReadResponse(220)
    if err != nil {
        text.Close()
        return nil, err
    }
    c := &Client{Text: text, conn: conn, serverName: host, localName: "localhost"}
    _, c.tls = conn.(*tls.Conn)
    return c, nil
}
```

You want to read this banner and decide whether to send mail based on its contents.

Since you have already read the banner yourself, and presumably will make a decision on that, instead of calling `smtp.NewClient()` you should then implement the rest of `NewClient()` in your own code, possibly something like this:

```
    client := &smtp.Client{Text: text, conn: conn, serverName: host, localName: "localhost"}
    _, client.tls = conn.(*tls.Conn)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i try to use your code : not print welcome message and die in timeout : https://play.golang.org/p/amy8NdSIsu6

Comment: @kingcope That code does not contain any evidence that you modified it in accordance with this answer. Please do so first.